# How to handle xPath returning Boolean instead of element?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have xPath which returns `boolean:true` instead of finding an element on the page.

Test page has a table with 2 columns and multiple rows. I'm testing if the rows have correct values. Below is the sample xPath where I'm checking the values for a given row.

`//tr[@class='af_table_data-row']//span[text()='To be Reviewed']` and `//span[text()='1']`

In firebug, this returns "`boolean:true`".

I'm lost on how can I read in Selenium. If I try to find as an element and then cast to boolean, it shows error as inconvertible types.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Consider the HTML below. The XPath in your question is checking whether there exists a tr-element in your HTML anywhere (because of the //), with the class 'af_data_table-row', that contains a span anywhere in the tr-element with text 'To be Reviewed' AND a span anywhere in the tr-element that contains the text '1'. Such an element exists, thus the value returned is true. By combining the the two span elements your XPath query with the `and` its result becomes a boolean result.

If you just want to get the two spans and check their values individually you could use the XPath: `//tr[@class='af_table_data-row']/td/span`. That will return an array with the 2 span elements. You can then write 2 separate checks to check the values.

However, consider that your original XPath already does enforce that the correct values are in the spans, so by checking for true as a return value from that it also does the check you are looking for, albeit in a less verbose way.

```
<table>
  <tr class="af_table_data-row"> 
    <td><span>To be Reviewed</span></td>
    <td><span>1</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured out the solution. You have to use JavascriptExecutor to read the value. Below is the sample code in case if anybody else encounter the same issue.

```
WebDriver driver = WebDriverFactory.getDriver();
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
return (Boolean) executor.executeScript("return document.evaluate(\"//tr[@class='af_table_data-row']//span[text()='To be Reviewed'] and //span[text()='1']\", document, null, XPathResult.BOOLEAN_TYPE, null).booleanValue");
```

Comment: I much prefer @jpjwolli's solution and reasoning